# Error 400: Bad request in Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth text Labeling task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, labeling

I am trying to use Amazon AWS to annotate my text data. It's a csv of 10 rows include header : "orgiginalText, replyText" and text data. I put my data in s3 bucker, create IAM with S3, sageMaker FullAccees. When I want to 'Create labeling job', it gave me error 400 Badrequest to connect to S3. is there anything else to be considered? I stucked 2 days in this small task and can't go forward.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. Can you access the S3 bucket from other means? Like AWS CLI from your local machine or from an EC2 instance?
2. Can you access the S3 bucket from a SageMaker notebook instance using the same execution role you created for SageMaker GroundTruth?
3. Does this issue persist with a particular bucket? Did you try creating another bucket, copy the data there and point to this S3 bucket instead?
4. Are you using the S3 bucket and Groundtruth labeling job in the same AWS region?

The 400 error can be due to variety of reasons. From S3 perspective, it may happen due to the bucket being in a `transitioned` state like creating/deleting etc.

From SageMaker's point, it can be due to many reasons few of which are listed here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html

Please try the above approaches and let me know your findings.